# Fibonacci number is negative

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

I have written the following code using dynamic programming technique but I am getting a negative number when I run Fibonacci for number 220. Is there a mistake in this program?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Fibonaci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" number ");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> memoized = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int fib = fibonanci(220, memoized);
        System.out.println(" Total Time "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    }

    private static int fibonanci(int n, HashMap<Integer, Integer> memoized) {
        System.out.println(" n " + n);
        if (memoized.containsKey(n)) {
            return memoized.get(n);
        }

        if (n <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n <= 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int febonani = fibonanci(n - 1, memoized)
                    + fibonanci(n - 2, memoized);
            System.out.println(" febonani " + febonani);
            if (!memoized.containsKey(n)) {
                memoized.put(n, febonani);
            }
            return febonani;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `List` (for example, `ArrayList`) here, instead of really big overhead of `HashMap`.

Comment: The line ```if (!memoized.containsKey(n))``` seems unnecessary, since if n wasn't in the memoized data structure at the start of the function, it wouldn't be in it at that point (unless you have multiple threads changing the structure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` instead of `int` / `Integer` to avoid the precision problems pointed out by Ivaylo (Java's `int` and `Integer` cannot represent unsigned integers of more than 2<sup>31</sup> bits, `long`/`Long` no more than 2<sup>63</sup>). BigInteger [supports arbitrary precision](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (limited only by the amount of memory available to the JVM).

Your code would look like:

```
 private static BigInteger fib(int n, HashMap<Integer, BigInteger> memoized) {
    System.out.println(" n = " + n);
    if (memoized.containsKey(n)) {
        return memoized.get(n);
    } else if (n <= 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    } else if (n <= 2) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        BigInteger sum = fib(n - 1, memoized).add(fib(n - 2, memoized));
        System.out.println(" fib(" + n + ") = " + sum;
        memoized.put(n, sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 It is important to mention a way to write a correct solution and that is something that my answer is missing.

Answer (score 9):

Fibonnacci numbers grow very fast and the integer in java fits only values from `-2^31` to `2^31 - 1`. the 220-th Fibonacci number is `4244200115309993198876969489421897548446236915`(about 2^151) which is way out of this range, thus you get [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: I would recommend adding approximation ([`~phi ^ n`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio)) to the answer.

Comment: I added the exact number :)

Comment: I meant, that it would show grow speed very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be an integer overflow. If i remember correctly the first overflow should happen with 47, or 48.

Maybe you can try using the BigInteger class for calculations like this.

Answer (score 1):

1836311903 is the largest fibonacci number (46th I suppose) that fits into the 32 bit signed integer range. You should be using BigInteger to avoid overflows while finding very large fibonacci numbers. And on another note, if your Hashmap keys are serial numbers anyway, you can use an array-based list.